# Most Recent Updates in Laravel

Tags: laravel-5, eloquent, vuejs2

I have a list of books in my database and each book have chapters. my models are

**Books.php**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Book extends Model
{
    protected $guarded = [];

    public function chapters()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Chapter::class);
    }
}
```

**Chapter.php**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Chapter extends Model
{
    protected $guarded = [];

    public function book()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Book::class);
    }
}
```

How can make a page that will show the books in order manner from latest to old?
Also, the order is based on the chapter being updated or added in a book. If one of the old books is being updated by adding 1 more chapter, that book will show first on the most recent updated books.
Thank you!

I am using Laravel 5.6 and Vue JS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Option 1:**

You should use joins in query:

```
$books = Books::select('books.*')
    ->leftJoin('chapters', 'chapters.book_id', '=', 'books.id')
    ->groupBy('books.id')
    ->orderByDesc('chapters.updated_at')
    ->get();
```

**Option 2:**

If you don't need paginate and want to show all books in one page, you can try to sort a collection by relation value.

Add latestChapter relation:

```
public function latestChapter()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Chapter::class)->orderByDesc('updated_at');
}
```

Get and sort:

```
$books = Books::with('latestChapter')->get();

$books = $books->sortByDesc(function($item){
        return $item->latestChapter ? $item->latestChapter->updated_at : '1970-01-01';
    });
```

Comment: is there any way to get only 5 most recently updated books to show on the view?

Comment: @Imperatura add `->limit(5)` to query.